# Carousel Javascript Indicators

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have created a carousel from scratch but i have no idea how to link a circle pointer to a correct img of carousel.

[This is the link of carousel GitHub Pages](https://gdemartino93.github.io/js-array-carousel/bonus/)

I m learning js and i have no idea about solution

These SlideUp and SlideDown are the 2 function to change the img.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```js
function slideDown(){
  attiva++
  if (attiva > ((imgArray.length)-1)) {
   attiva=0
  }
  
  bigActive.classList.remove("block");
  minActive.classList.remove("active-colonna");
  bigActive=document.getElementById("img-" + attiva);
  minActive=document.getElementById("min-" + attiva);
  bigActive.classList.add("block");
  minActive.classList.add("active-colonna");
  pointerActive.classList.remove("pointer-active")
  pointerActive=document.getElementById("nr-" + attiva);
  pointerActive.classList.add("pointer-active")
 }
```

Comment: HI Gianluca and welcome to SO. Please be sure to include the code relevant to your problem in the question as text. If possible, create a runnable example with a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so we can run your code on this very page. Please explain in detail what the expected result is, what you've tried to accomplish it and where it failed. This information makes it easier for us to help you get to the answer that you need. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: I'm assuming that you only manipulate the variable that sets which image it is by adding +1 or -1. Let those be helper methods instead, and create just one method that changes the current image. The "helper methods" when sends in a value that is +1 or -1 to the current value. I could write more to explain what I mean, if you edit your post and add your code for your carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the help i ve added code to a single function to slide the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I mean with "helper method" from the comments. You only need `changeImage()` and then the helper method `slideDown()` just sends in a number in `changeImage()`.

If clicking on the bullet points, they can send in a value based on their order, by calling `changeImage` directly.

```
function changeImage(attiva) {
  bigActive.classList.remove("block");
  minActive.classList.remove("active-colonna");
  bigActive=document.getElementById("img-" + attiva);
  minActive=document.getElementById("min-" + attiva);
  bigActive.classList.add("block");
  minActive.classList.add("active-colonna");
  pointerActive.classList.remove("pointer-active")
  pointerActive=document.getElementById("nr-" + attiva);
  pointerActive.classList.add("pointer-active")
}

function slideDown(){
  attiva++
  if (attiva > ((imgArray.length)-1)) {
   attiva=0
  }
  
  changeImage(attiva)
 }
```

[EDIT] Here below is a simple example of how you can connect your indicators ("circle pointers") to the `changeImage()` method.

```js
document.querySelector('navbar').addEventListener('click', indicatorClicked)

function indicatorClicked(event) {
  let target = event.target
  if (event.target.type == 'radio') {
    console.log(target.dataset.order)  // attiva
    
    // changeImage(target.dataset.order)
  }
}
```

```css
navbar > input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<navbar>
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="indicator" data-order="6" />
</navbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and i ve tried declaring the function on bullet points but i still dont understand how can i make this work

Comment: @Gianluca I updated my post with example of how to handle the indicators. That should give you enough pointers to continue on your own. Good luck!